# Slow wifi on Ubunutu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I'm hoping someone can help me with an issue I'm having with using wifi on my laptop.

I recently switched to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 10 on my laptop, when connecting to the main Virgin Hub or the 300mbs tp-link tl-wa850re wifi extender the wifi signal strength seems to decrease massively when I am not near either of the wifi devices. When the laptop is very close to the devices the wifi signal is strong and works well, however even if I am a meter away the wifi becomes slow. It is impossible to load pages in my room on my desk whereas when using Windows 10 the signal was still strong whilst at my desk.

Below is the pastebin of the wireless-info, hopefully someone can see a problem and help, cheers

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24856762/

Comment: yup, you were right. Couldn't find this answer for some reason upon first looking. Cheers mate